# Where can I found this photo like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, image-quality

**I found an sample photo like this**

[image]

I want learn editing that photo with my own picuture, but I cannot find the bigger size and better quality of that photo, Do you have a link or have personal photos that something like that? It's not problem if they are a person on that pictures, I will remove that and replace with my own picture, please help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's [Brainstorming/Resource Gathering](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Googling "Skyscraper Fisheye"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=skyscraper+fisheye&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=950&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYkYnqpInQAhVKl5QKHdyPBQEQ_AUIBigB) got me some good results like these [image 1](http://www.wallpaperup.com/85893/Dubai_Buildings_Skyscrapers_Clouds_Fog_Mist_Sunlight_Fisheye.html) and [image 2](https://alpha.wallhaven.cc/wallpaper/310760).

One could also use "tall building drone" or "skyscraper top"